# networkx digraph with edge attributes to csv

Tags: python, csv, networkx

I have a networkx DiGraph with edge attributes.
I am not able to write the network to a csv as edge list in the following format

```
# node1 node2 attr1 attr2 attr3
1, 2, color, time, weight
```

networkx.write_edgelist is able to write the edgelist but attributes are written as a string representation of the attributes dictionary which is not what I want.

Comment: Can you enrich you question with more details? It's hard to figure out what is happening. Please provide a minimal reproducible example including desired output.

Comment: There is nothing `pandas` in your question. Do not abuse tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass a list of attribute names to the function:

```
nx.write_edgelist(graph, 'file.csv', data=['attr1', 'attr2', 'attr3'])
```

In general, you should also read function documentation before using the function, especially if the function fails to behave.